# How can html be parsed as XML when containing '...&body='?

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have html file that is a well-formed xml document (tags are paired), but contains anchor like the one below:

`<a href="mailto:test@domain.com?subject=Hello&body=someMessageHere" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;">link</a>`

Xml parser invoked by XDocument.Load throws XmlException that says:

Additional information: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'.

How can I instruct parser that I '&body' is not an entity? Do I must escape '&' character?

Comment: Please post an example of your XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all HTML is going to be valid XML so you shouldn't try to parse it as such (although, in this case, it looks like you have some un-escpaped strings in the document that should probably get taken care of).

Instead, you should use something like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse your HTML and work with the document that way.

Comment: Is is possible that valid Html is not a valid Xml? I thought that html is just a narrowed Xml (?)

Comment: HTML is more flexible and forgiving (closing tags, character encoding, etc). Browsers are fairly forgiving when rendering HTML. XHTML is the only markup that *should* be guaranteed to be valid XML.